# Differnce between "%s" and "?%s" in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

Please could anyone of you tell me the difference between below syntax?

```
"%s"
```

```
uri += '?%s' % urllib.urlencode(params)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the different syntaxes, and looked at the results?

Comment: Nothing, it's the same, except one has a literal `?` in the front...

Comment: Hi, look at the bigger picture rather than downvoting a question

Comment: Probably because one of your strings is `"%s"` and the other is `"?%s"`. Not really surprising one of them has a ? in front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` signifies that after this point we would pass parameters for example `var1 = value` , `var2 = value`

https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl

A typical Google URL.

Answer (score 1):

It appends a '?' to the string. It doesnt do anything as a function. Most commonly used while appending parameters in some url.